# Programmatically find a moved file by the old name

Tags: tfs

In [an answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7421208/866022), Edward Thomson recommends using `QueryItems` to find a moved file by its old file name.

However, I can't seem to figure this out.  It looks like it's part of `Microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.server.dll`, but I can't seem to locate this anywhere.  I wonder if this is a DLL on the TFS server itself (which I don't have access to at the moment).  If so, it won't help me for what I need.

How can I programmatically find the moved file name by the old file name in TFS 2010?

Comment: Apologies, as jessehouwing correctly points out below, I meant the `GetItems` method call.  (The TFS Java SDK, once upon a time, called that method "query items" to disambiguate from the `Get...` methods that *download items*.  And I'm hopelessly stuck in the past.)  I've updated that original answer to reflect.

Answer (score 3):

If the server you are talking to is at least TFS 2010 then you can do this using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlServer.GetChangesForChangeset().  Once you determine the changeset that the rename occurred in using QueryHistory, call GetChangesForChangeset and pass "true" for the "includeMergeSourceInfo" parameter.  This will populate the "MergeSources" property on each Change object.

With the switch to "slotmode" in 2010 a rename in TFS Version Control is very similar to a "Branch and Delete" operation under the covers.  Because of this, renames are actually tracked as part of "merge history".

So, if you iterate over the changes and find the change that has a MergeSource that is both a rename (see IsRename property) and has your source item then you will have found the target item of the rename operation.

Answer (score 1):

I think he actually means the GetItem(s) or QueryHistory methods of the

```
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlServer
Namespace:  Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client
Assembly:  Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client (in Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.dll)
```

See [this msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.versioncontrolserver.aspx) for more information on these items. You can specify a VersionSpec which can include a Deletion Identifier. If I remember correctly though, you'll need to be careful if you want to use this code against older versions of TFS. In TFS2010 slotmode was introduced, which is more efficient and can track filename changes across versions. Before that a rename basically came down to a Delete of the old version and an Add of the new version, no relationship stored.

Comment: Yes - I did indeed mean `GetItems`, thank you for clarifying.  One minor note (more trivia than anything else) around the differences in rename handling between TFS2010 and pre-2010:  in TFS2010, it's actually *more* like an add and a delete than before.  (You'll see this reflected in pending changes on a delete where the source has a "delete, source rename" pending change.)  This actually makes it easier to solve this problem of "where did my file go" because you can query with deletionid.  In TFS2008 (IIRC) you'd have to query the old filename at a version it was known to exist.

Comment: I'm not able to get the new file name by passing the old file name into either GetItems or QueryHistory.  I'm returned the changesets right up to the rename (including the rename), but I don't see any members that return the new file name.  Nor do I see any changesets post rename.  Am I doing something wrong?